# Modifying .bashrc

Tags: python, bash

I'm not very familiar with using VIM or bash but I'm trying to get the google gmail API to work.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#step_4_run_the_sample

At the bottom is has the instructions

```
AttributeError: 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute 'urlparse'
```

This error can occur in Mac OSX where the default installation of the "six" module (a dependency of this library) is loaded before the one that pip installed. To fix the issue, add pip's install location to the PYTHONPATH system environment variable:

Determine pip's install location with the following command:

```
pip show six | grep "Location:" | cut -d " " -f2
```

When I run this, I get `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`

Add the following line your you ~/.bashrc file, replacing  with the value determined above:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<pip_install_path>
```

My `.bashrc` file has 1 line in it:

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`

(There isn't a break between `export` or the rest, SO is creating the break when I paste it in)

Reload your ~/.bashrc file in any open terminal windows using the following command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

However, when I type `cd ~` and `ls -a` I don't see `.bashrc` only `.bash_sessions`

How do I open and modify `.bashrc`?

Here is the error file

```
Installing collected packages: six, httplib2, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, rsa, oauth2client, simplejson, uritemplate, google-api-python-client
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 726, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 746, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/0p/503b1d894jz0z8rfyhw6jmzh0000gn/T/pip-xPddj0-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

When I run the `quickstart.py` file:

```
Morgans-iMac:iMac morganallen$ python quickstar.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstar.py", line 73, in <module>
    main()
  File "quickstar.py", line 57, in main
    credentials = get_credentials()
  File "quickstar.py", line 45, in get_credentials
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 135, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/tools.py", line 199, in run_flow
    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 135, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1991, in step1_get_authorize_url
    return _update_query_params(self.auth_uri, query_params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 491, in _update_query_params
    parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(uri)
AttributeError: 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute 'urlparse'
```

Comment: If you don't have a .bashrc file, you can always add one.  Type `vim .bashrc` and vim will open a new file called .bashrc.  Then enter the information into the file as instructed.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that OS X may not actually read `.bashrc` by default and you might need to use `.bash_profile` for that (or read `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`).

Comment: I don't have a `.bash_profile` file either...just `.bash_sessions' should I add that to that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to have a `.bashrc`. Just copy the `.bashrc` from `/etc/skel/` to your home directory. So running `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc` should fix your problem. In case you don't have the directory `/etc/skel/` then simply do `touch ~/.bashrc` to create an empty file in your home directory called `.bashrc`.

Now you can append the `EXPORT` line by using echo. i.e. `echo "export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python" >> ~/.bashrc`.
Then you can reload it using `source` command.

---

The error from your log seems to be related to your install process of `six`. Try to reinstall it using the command `pip install --ignore-installed six`.

Comment: Hey @NaCl I created the .bashrc file (and updated my question) but still having issues. Any thoughts?

Comment: @MorganAllen I've edited my answer appropriately.

Comment: Hey @NaCl I ran `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client --ignore-installed six` and that worked. When I went to run the program, I'm seeing the error `AttributeError: 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute 'urlparse'`. I'm confused as I followed their instructions and updated the `.bashrc` file...

Comment: I added the error log. It looks like it still isn't reading it from the proper file.

Comment: I took a snapshot of my directory - http://imgur.com/inQJAlz

Comment: And a snapshot of my `.bashrc` file - http://imgur.com/yYW3Oan

Comment: @MorganAllen I don't think we should discuss this here in comment section. Please edit your answer if you want to provide further information to your specific problem.
Anyways, it seems that `google-python-api` is the cause of your problem, so downgrading by running `pip install -I google-api-python-client==1.3.2` might help.

Comment: I created a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775056/issues-with-gmail-api-client